# Add missing lines in file if timestamp isn't continous

Tags: python

I have .csv file containing continous data with timestamp (but in some cases some lines-minutes can be missing) and I need to write some script which will go through this file and add these missing lines with average values of neighboring lines.

Example of current data:

```
_yyyy,_mm,_dd,_HH,_MM,_SS,T
2015,01,01,00,00,00,-5.0
2015,01,01,00,02,00,-5.2
2015,01,01,00,03,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,04,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,05,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,06,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,07,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,08,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,09,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,11,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,14,00,-5.3
```

and I would like to add these lines to their correct place:

```
2015,01,01,00,01,00,-5.1
2015,01,01,00,10,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,12,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,13,00,-5.3
```

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Show us what you have do so far. Share your code.

Comment: to be honest I don't have much, basicaly just load file and go line by line, but I don't know how to continu :(

Comment: Start by breaking down the problem: Read and keep the entire file in memory, so you can look ahead to the next line for the purpose of averaging. Loop through the lines, checking if the minute value (converted to a number) is exactly one more than the last one. If the distance is bigger, figure out how to inspect the surrounding lines and form an average. Output or insert the constructed line. Write some code, and for each of these specific steps you could come here and search or ask for help again.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the code below. It does what you expect but in a different way. First it reads csv file line by line using readlines function. This creates a list of strings, each string corresponds to a row. Then it strips out `\n` new line character and split's the string into another list of individual cell values. After that it performs sorting operation on this nested list and writes the list back to csv file.

```
with open("data.csv") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# removes '\n' character
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
# split each row to individual cell values
content = [x.split(',') for x in content]

# for sorting purpose, we need to remove the csv header. Before removing let's store the header to a new variable
csv_header = ','.join(content[0])
csv_header += '\n'

del content[0] # removes csv header from the list

# the values must be enclosed in single or double quotes. 
content.append(['2015','01','01','00','01','00','-5.1'])
content.append(['2015','01','01','00','10','00','-5.3'])
content.append(['2015','01','01','00','12','00','-5.3'])
content.append(['2015','01','01','00','13','00','-5.3'])

# before sorting
print(content)

# sorting using the timestamp value
content.sort(key = lambda x: x[6])

# after sorting
print(content)

# opens a new file for writing, you may use the same filename here. Then it will overwrite the original csv file. 
f = open('output.csv','w')
f.write(csv_header) # writes the csv header
for i in content:
    # converts list to string 
    row = ','.join(i)
    row += '\n' # adds a new line character
    f.write(row) # writes the string to output.csv
f.close()
```

data.csv file

```
_yyyy,_mm,_dd,_HH,_MM,_SS,T
2015,01,01,00,00,00,-5.0
2015,01,01,00,02,00,-5.2
2015,01,01,00,03,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,04,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,05,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,06,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,07,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,08,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,09,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,11,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,14,00,-5.3
```

output.csv file

```
_yyyy,_mm,_dd,_HH,_MM,_SS,T
2015,01,01,00,00,00,-5.0
2015,01,01,00,01,00,-5.1
2015,01,01,00,02,00,-5.2
2015,01,01,00,03,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,04,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,05,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,06,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,07,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,08,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,09,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,11,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,14,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,10,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,12,00,-5.3
2015,01,01,00,13,00,-5.3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for, I don't see anywhere newly added lines

Comment: @user1928543 The script works fine and adds new lines. Check my updated answer. But i'm not sure whether it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be run via Python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_average(val1, val2):
    return (val1 + val2) / 2

def create_row(prev_date, prev_T, next_T):
    missed_date = prev_date + timedelta(minutes=1)
    row = {
            '_yyyy': missed_date.year,
            '_mm': missed_date.month,
            '_dd': missed_date.day,
            '_HH': missed_date.hour,
            '_MM': missed_date.minute,
            '_SS': missed_date._SS,
            'T': get_average(prev_T, next_T)
    }

def create_datetime(row):
    dt = datetime.datetime(row['_yyyy'], row['_mm'], row['_dd'], row['_HH'], row['_MM'], row['_SS'])

def is_minute_line_missing(prev_date, cur_date):
    if prev_date is None:
        return False
    elif cur_date - timedelta(minutes=1) != prev_date:
        return True

def complete_csv():
    with open('path/to/csv/file') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

        prev_date = None
        cur_date = None
        prev_T = None

        for row in reader:
            cur_date = create_datetime(row)
            if is_minute_line_missing(prev_date, cur_date):
                missed_row = create_row(prev_date, prev_T, row['T'])
                # insert this missed_row in new file or whatever
            else:
                prev_date = cur_date
                prev_T = row['T']
```